# Issues with accessing individual elements of an array in perl

Tags: perl

I am having trouble in parsing an array. I have used

```
print Dumper($variable)
```

to get

```
$VAR1 = [
          'joshn',
          'taylor'
        ];
```

I need to get the individual elements josh and taylor. How can I obtain it?

Answer (score 2):

```
# get last element 
my $last = $variable->[-1];

# get first element
my $first = $variable->[0]; # cryptic equivalent: $$variable[0] (don't use it) 
# get second element
my $second = $variable->[1]; # also $$variable[1]

# same effect as above
my ($first, $second) = @{$variable}; # or @$variable for short
```

Comment: @Kenosis yes, but there are reasons to dislike them

Comment: I prefer the dereferencing arrow you've used, but thought I'd include the above for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `$variable` is a ref to an array, then

```
for(@{$variable}) {
    print $_, "\n"
}
```

*EDIT*: To access last element in an array:

```
my @array = @{$variable};
print $array[$#array];
```

Comment: How can I directly access the last element rather than using for loop

Comment: I'll answer that even if it has nothing to do with your original question. This is not a forum.